# Setting an HTMLElement using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm converting my old JavaScript to TypeScript. I have a Table Of Contents JSX component that I use to easily scroll to a specific heading.

I use a function to find the total scroll offset required to scroll to the specified heading. After converting this to a '.tsx' file, I get an error:

> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 107 more.

```
// TOC.tsx
...
const accumulateOffsetTop = ( el: HTMLElement | null, totalOffset = 0 ) => {
  while ( el ) {
    totalOffset += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop
    el = el.offsetParent // <- Error here
  }
  return totalOffset
}
...
```

This function is called here:

```
// TOC.tsx
...
export default function Toc(
  { headingSelector, getTitle, getDepth, ...rest }
) {
  const { throttleTime = 200, tocTitle = `Contents` } = rest
  const [headings, setHeadings] = useState( {
    titles: [],
    nodes: [],
    minDepth: 0,
    offsets: [],
  } )
  const [open, setOpen] = useState( false )
  const [active, setActive] = useState()
  const ref = useRef()
  useOnClickOutside( ref, () => setOpen( false ) )
  useEffect( () => {
    const selector = headingSelector || Array.from(
      { length: 6 }, ( _, i ) => `main > h` + ( i + 1 )
    )
    const nodes = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( selector ) )
    const titles = nodes.map( node => ( {
      title: getTitle ? getTitle( node ) : node.innerText,
      depth: getDepth ? getDepth( node ) : Number( node.nodeName[1] ),
    } ) )
    const minDepth = Math.min( ...titles.map( h => h.depth ) )
    const startingOffsets = nodes.map( el => accumulateOffsetTop( el ) - 100 )
    setHeadings( { titles, nodes, minDepth, startingOffsets } )
  }, [headingSelector, getTitle, getDepth] )

  const scrollHandler = throttle( () => {
    const { titles, nodes } = headings
    const offsets = nodes.map( el => accumulateOffsetTop( el ) )
    const activeIndex = offsets.findIndex(
      offset => offset > window.scrollY + 120
    )
    setActive( activeIndex === -1 ? titles.length - 1 : activeIndex - 1 )
  }, throttleTime )
  useEventListener( `scroll`, scrollHandler )
...
}
```

How do I set the types of the parameters passed to `accumulateOffsetTop`?

Answer (score 2):

The error gets thrown because `el.offsetParent` is of type `Element | null` and not of type `HTMLElement | null`. The reason `el.offsetParent` does not return an `HTMLElement` by default is because `el.offsetParent` could also result in different types of `Element` such as `SVGElement` ([issue#156](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/156)). You will have to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) here and maybe make sure the returned value is an `HTMLElement` if necessary.

Comment: When I log the values passed to the function, they are the <h1/> headers that I'd like to use in the TOC. How do assert that they are the <h1/> elements?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I ended up uses type assertions.

```
const accumulateOffsetTop = ( el: HTMLElement, totalOffset = 0 ) : number => {
  while ( el ) {
    totalOffset += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop
    el = el.offsetParent as HTMLElement
  }
  return totalOffset
}
```